# Piix4_SMBus: 000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller bus not enabled

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, kali-linux

На vmware стоит образ kali 2017.3, после одного из обновлений при перезагрузке выдает такую строку, что не дает мне подключиться к сети.
Попробовал способ указанный здесь: https://askubuntu.com/questions/691729/piix4-smbus-0000007-3-host-smbus-controller-bus-not-enabled
Также пробовал https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlzsZkZldMM 
Ничего из этого не работает, собственно да и файл /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf не существует даже. Способ из видео работает отчасти, ошибка не появляется, но и сеть тоже.
Никогда с такой проблемой не сталкивался и не имею понятия с какой стороны даже подойти.
Пробовал поставить деб чистый, такая же ошибка сразу.

Comment: Если blacklist.conf не существует, то его можно создать.

Comment: Естественно я и это пробовал